# Поиск дублей запросом

Tags: sql

Есть следующие таблицы:

```
1) patient с полями: fam, im, ot, policeid
2) police с полями: keyid, seriya, nomer, patientid
3) poseshenie с полями: data, patientid
```

Нужно найти запросом всех пациентов, у которых поле police.nomer дублируется и вывести в таком виде:

```
fam, im, ot, seriya, nomer, data
```

P.S. вывести нужно с дублирующимися записями

Например если поля fam, im, ot разные но ser и nomer одинаковые вывести так:

```
Иванов Иван Сергеевич 01 333 20.01.2019
Петров Иван Сергеевич 01 333 21.01.2019
```

Пробовала так, но выдает ошибку что групповая функция в where не разрешена

```
select p.fam, p.im, p.ot, trunc(pos.dat), pol.seriya, pol.nomer from patient p
       left outer join poseshenie pos on pos.patientid = p.keyid
       left outer join police pol on pol.patientid = p.keyid
       where count(*) > 1 group by pol.nomer, pol.seriya
```

Comment: Делаете `WHERE COUNT(*) > 1 GROUP BY police.nomer`. Для вывода дублей можно сделать `WHERE police.nomer IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: Не поняла? Все поля могут иметь разное значение, но мне нужно вывести только те записи, которые имеют одинаковое значение в полях seriya и nomer

Comment: А можно запрос целиком привести? А то я уже пол часа потратила не могу до конца понять

Comment: это вам какую то ерунду сказали, count() не может быть в where. А после group by у вас не останется индивидуальных записей. я бы предложил `where exists(select 1 from police pol1 where pol1.nomer=pol.nomer and pol.patientid!=pol1.patientid`. Если идти путем group by то where nomer in(select nomer from police group by nomer having count(1)>1)`

Comment: А можно весь запрос написать, чтобы и поля из других таблиц вывести?

Comment: @Mike, в MySQL count работает с where. Хотя соглашусь с вами, не лучшая практика. Лучше использовать having

Comment: я в oracle работаю

Comment: @ArchDemon "_в MySQL count работает с where_". продемонстрируйте на каком нибудь sqlfiddle. Лично у меня "invalid use of group function", что абсолютно логично, потому что часть where выполняется до group by, а следовательно агрегированные данные в это время еще не получены

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна раз Oracle (что стоило указать в тегах вопроса), то третий вариант. берете ваш текущий запрос, без where и group by. В часть select добавляете еще одну колонку `count(1) over(partition by pol.nomer) cnt` после чего оборачиваете в еще один запрос и там берете записи с cnt>1 (`select * from (ваш-запрос) x where cnt>1`)

Comment: Все равно не то получаю. Например я получила 8 записей в запросе где поле nomer = 0000000000000000 для одного и того же пациента. Т.е. А мне нужно вывести всех пациентов, у которых одинаковые серия и номер полиса.

Comment: А можете пояснить строчку count(1) over(partition by pol.nomer) cnt  что она делает?

Comment: Она считает количество строк для каждой группы значений pol.nomer. Дружеский совет: перечитайте еще раз справочник по sql-диалекту Oracle.